# dynamically select columns and values with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Say I have a table like:

```
product         market          idea
A                FG             cool
C                BG             sad
T                B              super
```

In the frontend the user can select any value from product market or idea and also any column to filter. So for example the user can select product = A and market = FG.

The goal is to construct a query using sqlalchemy orm to gather the columns the user selected and also gather the values and dynamically generate the query as:

```
select * from my_table where product = A and market = FG
```

Here is my attempt:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String,and_,insert,select,Integer,delete
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Define model
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product = Column(String)
    market = Column(String)
    idea = Column(String)

# Create a connection to database
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg://postgres:mypass@localhost:5432/postgres')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create a session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Bulk Insert Data
session.execute(
    insert(MyTable),
    [
        {"id":1,"product":"BG","market":"JY","idea":"sad"},
        {"id":2,"product":"GF","market":"HN","idea":"happy"},
    ]
    )
session.commit()


def dynamic_query(selected_filters):
    # Initialize the base query
    # query = session.query(MyTable)
    query = select(MyTable)

    # Build the dynamic filters
    filters = []
    for key, value in selected_filters.items():
        filters.append(getattr(MyTable, key) == value)

    # Apply the filters to the query
    if filters:
        query = query.where(and_(*filters))

    # Execute the query
    results = session.scalars(query).all()
    print(results)

    return results

# Example usage
user_selected_filters = {'product': 'BG', 'market': 'HN'}
result = dynamic_query(user_selected_filters)
print(result)
```

Result is:
[]

But it should contain all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you are using `and_` when I think you want `or_`.  Otherwise the input data is bad.  Using `and_` requires that every row has columns that match all those conditions.

For example this data would return a single match, `id=3`:

```
    [
        {"id":1,"product":"BG","market":"JY","idea":"sad"},
        {"id":2,"product":"GF","market":"HN","idea":"happy"},
        {"id":3,"product":"BG","market":"HN","idea":"glad"},
    ]
```

Comment: right thanks, i get the result like this: `[<__main__.MyTable object at 0x1030e0dd0>]` , how can i get like that `[MyTable(id=3,product='BG',market='HN',idea='glad')]`

Comment: That is just diff between printing I think.  You have the results in `result` in `result = dynamic_query(user_selected_filters)`.